# Migrating to Azure Sql Database with external dependencies in another database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

The question: Is it possible to point a view in database A running on Azure SQL Database service to tables/views on a SQL server running in a VM? I've tried external tables but come up short.

Scenario: 
Two applications that is exchanging data, from two different vendors. 
We've got three databases in total. One for each application and an integration database with views that both applications use either directly or through views.

The issue now is that we want to migrate to Azure and would prefer to use the Azure SQL Database service as much as possible, but one of the applications is not ready for it and therefor it's database has to be hosted on either a managed instance or in a VM.

The issue now is that there's view's in database A (running on Azure SQL Database service) that points to views and tables in the integration database, which again references tables in database B (running on SQL Server on the VM).

Comment: Can you handle some latency? i.e. refresh a local copy of the table every 5 minutes?

Comment: We could, but would prefer not to as we would have to refresh the data every time we access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no".  You can use external tables to query other SQL Azure databases, but there is no exact analogue for linked servers in Azure SQL Database.  You can use SQL Azure Managed Instance (which supports SQL-SQL linked servers but not arbitrary linked servers).

There is a workaround, however.  You can run SQL Server in an Azure VM and have it point to SQL Azure as a target as well as the other sources you want to connect.  Then you can push data to/from Azure SQL DB using the SQL Server in a VM.  You don't have the same management overhead in this approach since you don't really need to host data in the SQL Server if you don't want to do so.  Note that this will be slower than doing direct connections to SQL Azure, but you can try to do this for a period of time if it would help you during a migration.